# In my code I use p-calendar from the primeng library and it is displayed upside down

Tags: angular, primeng

The minutes and hours are replaced in the display for example when the time is `02:55` it shows me `55:02`
The problem is only in the display of the control and it picks up the time in the best and correct way.

The time is displayed correctly as in this image: [image: image-1]

But it doesn't solve my problem which is in the p-calendar control like in this picture: [image: image-2]

This is the code:

```
 <p-calendar appendTo="body" [timeOnly]="true" formControlName="time"></p-calendar>
```

And this is the display on the screen:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64LJD.png)

I would like to know if there is a possibility to fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make a model of type Date

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date" appendTo="body"></p-calendar>
export class MyComponent {
  date: Date;
}
```

or

```
<p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date" hourFormat="24"></p-calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `minDate` option like this:

```
<p-calendar appendTo="body" [timeOnly]="true" formControlName="time" [minDate]="date"></p-calendar>
```

and declare its value in `.ts` file:

```
date = new Date()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding a `direction: ltr` line to the _calendar.scss file
so:

```scss
&.p-datepicker-timeonly {
    .p-timepicker {
        border-top: 0 none;
        direction: ltr;
    }
}
```